# is it possible to change the HTML element values with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code directly embedded in one PHP page,

```
<select name="language_levels[]" class="span2">
    <option value="beginner">beginner</option>
    <option value="intermediate">intermediate</option>
    <option value="fluent">fluent</option>
    <option value="native">native</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to make one of the options checked based on the records in the database, so in the PHP page, I could simple ***echo*** the above code out, and make one option checked (for example, **beginner**). However, I think this is not the correct way (because it involves lots of condition statement to decide the correct code to output, i.e. **echo**), so I am wondering is there a method (like JavaScript/Jquery) for php to set the option value.

Comment: There is no need to use lots of conditional statements, one `if` statement is enough.

Comment: Can't you generate the list of "option" using php and in the loop, you can decide which one to select.

Comment: You just set the value of the select element, `<select name="language_levels[]" class="span2" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">`

Comment: @adeneo You method doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

```
$value = 'beginner';
$options = array('beginner', 'intermediate', 'fluent', 'native');

<select name="language_levels[]" class="span2">
  <?php foreach($options as $o) {
    $selected = $o === $value ? "selected='selected'" : "";
    echo "<option value='$o' $selected>$o</option>";
  } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Congrats on your ternary skills but your examples would be better understood by beginners if you avoided them.

Comment: @Sosukodo Thanks, well, ternary operator is not very complicated and many languages support it, `condition ? true : false`, it makes the code shorter and a programmer should know how it works. Am I wrong?

Comment: @undefined I agree that ternary syntax is an important skill, but it is less readable to newbies since it is usually absent from basic courses and tutorials. Doesn't hurt add a comment (`//ternary conditional`) to help with guiding towards appropriate documentation, or a couple parenthesis to visually set the ternary operation apart from the variable assignment. You're right that it's not *necessary*, but it's certainly helpful.

Comment: Your **options** array is not correct ! :p thanks anyway

Comment: @undefined: I don't think either of us are wrong. Personally, I don't use them. I try to be verbose with my code just for clarity. Maybe that's why I brought it up! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how a webpage is made (with PHP):

1. The user asks for `example.com/foo.php` from your server
2. Your server runs all of the PHP code at `foo.php` to generate an HTML file
3. That HTML file gets sent back to the user's machine
4. That user's machine parses the HTML and runs any Javascript within

As you can see, using javascript/jquery isn't just wrong, it's impossible, because the Javascript would have no idea which option to select (unless you `echo`-ed out a JS variable for it, but if you're going to do that why not just `echo` out the `selected` attribute in the first place right?).

So really there is absolutely nothing wrong with setting the `selected` attribute of the appropriate option using PHP.  As undefined commented however, there are ways to avoid having to write millions of conditionals.  One example would be to do what undefined suggests, and another would be to build your own custom select tag logic as a class or function.

And yet another way would be to use one of the many great PHP frameworks that provide such classes/functions for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id = "level" name="language_levels[]" class="span2">
    <option value="beginner">beginner</option>
    <option value="intermediate">intermediate</option>
    <option value="fluent">fluent</option>
    <option value="native">native</option>
</select>
```

By using jquery you can do this

```
var prevSelected='';
$(function()
{
    // get checked value via ajax call
    ajax(url,function(data)
    {
       if(prevSelected!='')
          $("#level option[value='" + prevSelected + "']").removeAttr("selected","selected");

       $("#level option[value='" + data + "']").attr("selected","selected");
       prevSelected=data;
    });

});
```